# How to configure 802.1X without a configuration file?

Tags: macos, network

After upgrading to Lion, all my 802.1X configurations are gone. There also  does not seem to be a possibility to configure them via the system preferences:

[image: 802.1X]

It just tells me to get a configuration file from my system administrator.

**Question:**

How can I create a profile manually like before, or, if this is not possible, can I create a configuration file myself with the data I have and how?

**Update:**

It turned out that it was sufficient to just provide my credentials at the when I connected to the network. I was just confused as there was not profile anymore in the preferences as you can see in the screenshot above. I hope the accepted answer will still be useful.

Comment: Yep, that's how 802.1x works. You authenticate (usually but not necessarily "on the domain"), and you're provided a certificate to install.

Comment: Did you see a popup dialog for the certificate or is it properly signed? (Or do you know in this case?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a  .mobileconfig file that includes your 802.1X profile. Acording to apple ( http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4772 ) you can use the Server extensions of Lion to create it. Alternatively (and easier ) the Iphone Configuration Utility ( http://support.apple.com/kb/dl851 ) can also create it. If you upgrade to Lion from Snow leopard any existing profile is migrated.

Comment: It turned out that it was even easier. I could just type in my credentials at the prompt and it worked. Not sure if this is because I configured it previously. As you can see, in there are not configured settings in the above list. Anyway, creating a profile with the configuration utility is a neat tip. Thanks!